# ionic serve command does not start ionic app

Tags: ionic-framework, npm

I am new in ionic framework. I have node js 6.8.1 installed in my computer. I tried to create an ionic project. Here are the commands I used:

```
npm install -g cordova

npm -install -g ionic

ionic start myapp blank

cd myapp

ionic serve
```

but every time I try this last command, this error message appears:

> Couldn't find ionic.config.json file. are you in an ionic project?

I tried many times with different versions of node. How can I correct it?

Answer (score 0):

ionic start yourAppName blank

1. Move to your app project folder and add a platform: For example: android or Ios Use the following commands.

   ionic platform add android

And for ios, if you are using a mac for development then..

```
ionic platform add ios
```

2. And Type: `ionic serve --lab` To load the app in your browser.. To build the apk use the command `ionic build android` or `ionic build ios`
3. To run on the app on your phone.. connect the phone with a USB Cable and enable developer option on your phone. Then use the command `ionic run android` or ionic run ios to install the app on your phone (or iphone for ios app).
4. To run the app on the emulator : `ionic emulate android`

> Please use - ionic to start and not npm... in your code :)
>   Hope this helps.. A small Typo... :)

Comment: when i type the command  ionic platform add android in the project folder, i have the same error message **Couldn't find ionic.config.json file. are you in an ionic project?**

Comment: @HOLYSPIRIT Please note that you are supposed to use ------ ionic start myapp blank --- and not 'npm start myapp blank'.. So please make a new app now with ionic prefix and not npm :)

Comment: Finally, i resolved the problem by creating a file named ionic.config.json in the root directory of my app. Whithin this file, i added the javascript object below :
   **{
      "name":"my application name",
      "app_id" :"app id of my app"
   }**

and now, when i type the command ionic serve, my app start in the browser.